# Database results according user location

Tags: mysql, database, location

i'm working on a project which has a MYSQL database. The table 'doctors' contains 4 columns (id-name-address-telephone).In this project,users have to log in and then according their location they can see the doctors(results) near them. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question  .So you can use latitude and longitude  as two fields in your doc table .It determines the exact position of the doctor .

Then you will have to fetch user lat and long from mobile device and calculate distance using simple distance formula or google library for more accurate results .
Checkout https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro